# how to resize Azure VHD files via api

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

resizing Windows Azure VHD files

how can I create Azure VHD files via page blob api?
how can I resize Azure VHD files via rest api?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create Azure VHD files via page blob api? how can I resize Azure VHD files via rest api?

Azure Storage is the cloud storage solution for **storing** our data on cloud, it is a cloud storage service. Page blob is one of Azure Blob Storage and VHD could be stored as a page blob, currently Azure storage REST API provides these [operations on page blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/operations-on-page-blobs), it enable us to put a range of pages into a page blob, but page blob REST API is not designed for creating VM image/VHD file. If you’d like to capture Azure VM image, you could capture image via ARM Explorer or PowerShell. For details about “capture the image”, please refer to [this article](http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-capture-your-own-custom-virtual-machine-image-under-azure-resource-manager-api/).